# определение светофоров по цвету opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

как с помощью open cv и пайтон определить светиться ли переход.
Мой способ дает очень много false true результатов.
фото до распозания
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZeKoZenE3L42eWUxkuvlG1VTzCSl8Mm3/view?usp=sharing

фото после распозания
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tWBrk2UF5J6TGB60Dz3Nf-tmod41oooL/view?usp=sharing

```
for s in contours2:
x2, y2, w2, h2 = cv2.boundingRect(s)
if 1600 > (cv2.contourArea(s)) > 500:
    (x2, y2), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(s)
    (x2, y2), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(s)

    center = (int(x2), int(y2))
    radius = int(radius)
    radius2 = int(radius)+10

    cv2.circle(image_copy, center, radius2, (255, 0, 0), 2)#я хочу эти круги (синие) проверять на наличие черного цвета по контуру и мне кажеться что это должно помочь!

    cv2.circle(image_copy, center, radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('All contours with bounding box', image_copy)
```

Мне кажеться что если добавить еще один фильтр в cv2.circle(image_copy, center, radius2, (255, 0, 0), 2)#я хочу эти круги (синие) и проверять на наличие черного цвета по контуру и мне кажеться что это должно помочь!
Но я понятия не имею как првоерить цвет последний пикселей контура cv2.circle(image_copy, center, radius2, (255, 0, 0), 2)
Заранее спасибо

Comment: По звуку звонка проще детектировать.  Или по видео (светофор мигает секциями поочередно).

Comment: хотелось бы узнать на счет секций, Вы имеете ввиду изменения обьектов? то как быть, ведь там еще и машины ездят и люди ходят?

Comment: Используете всю ту информацию о светофоре, чем от отличается от людей и машин: небольшие размеры, периодичность мигания, цвет сигналов, неподвижность светофора, примерное положение на картинке (а если камера стационарная, то и положение фиксированое). Но по звуку проще, очень он специфический, трудно перепутать этот звонок.

Comment: сейчас стараюсь реализовать примерное положение на картинке, если можете взглянуть на мой вопрос, буду очень Вам признательна! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1338607/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-opencv-%d0%b8-python